# RoR rspec failing test with error 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am following Hartls Rails tutorial and I am stuck at the end of Chapter 6.
Suddenly some of my test are failing with the same error:

```
C:\Users\JMA\Projekte\sampleapp>bundle exec rspec spec/
.F......F...FFF....

Failures:

  1) User
     Failure/Error: it { should respond_to(:passwors_confirmation)}
       expected #<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
 created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$04$OMnlZgC9yWhxbQizs8MG
9uPMCd8LmMlO5MZzkuQyM8it..."> to respond to :passwors_confirmation
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User when name is not present when email format is valid should be valid
     Failure/Error: expect(@user).to be_valid
       expected #<User id: nil, name: " ", email: "user@foo.COM", created_at: ni
l, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$04$PtGxi4DjJWFezLFYy1jW5eaI7C/xxyBLXAG
zPepflo8r..."> to be valid, but got errors: Name can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:51:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:49:in `each'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:49:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User when name is not present return value of authenticate method with vali
d password
     Failure/Error: before { @user.safe }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `safe' for #<User:0x502bc30>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:86:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User when name is not present return value of authenticate method with inva
lid password
     Failure/Error: before { @user.safe }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `safe' for #<User:0x50333a0>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:86:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) User when name is not present return value of authenticate method with inva
lid password
     Failure/Error: before { @user.safe }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `safe' for #<User:0x503b848>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:86:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.52003 seconds
19 examples, 5 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:16 # User
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:47 # User when name is not present when email f
ormat is valid should be valid
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:90 # User when name is not present return value
 of authenticate method with valid password
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:96 # User when name is not present return value
 of authenticate method with invalid password
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:97 # User when name is not present return value
 of authenticate method with invalid password

Randomized with seed 37132
```

My user_specs.rb looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                    password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:passwors_confirmation)}

  it { should be_valid }

describe"when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid}


describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid}   
end 

describe "when name is to long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid}
end 

describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
        adresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo. 
            foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
        adresses.each do |invalid_adress|
            @user.email = invalid_adress
            expect(@user).not_to be_valid   
        end
    end     
end

describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
        addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
        addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        expect(@user).to be_valid
        end
    end
end     

describe "when email adress is already taken" do
    before do
        user_with_same_email = @user.dup
        user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
        user_with_same_email.save
    end
    it {should_not be_valid}
end     

it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

describe "when password is not present" do
    before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                       password: " ", password_confirmation: " ")
end
it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "with a password that's to short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
end

describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.safe }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
        it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
        let (:user_for_inavlid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

        it { should_not eq user_for_inavlid_password }
        specify { expect(user_for_inavlid_password).to be_false }
    end 
end 

end
end
```

users.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence:true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

has_secure_password     
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

end
```

It appeared after adding the password and password_confirmation attributes to the User model. The where passing untill then. I have continued the tutorial becasue I have read about this failure and that it will be dealt with at a later stage of the tutorial. Now my tests are still failing and I do not know why. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you show the error so that people can help you fix the error?  Show all the lines of the error message, not just the first few words.

Comment: Sorry, was my first time asking a question here. I added the whole error message. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The stack trace says:

```
Failure/Error: before { @user.safe }  
NoMethodError:  
  undefined method `safe' for #<User:0x503b848>  
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:86:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It's telling you some key pieces of information:

- The problem is happening on line 86 of `user_spec.rb`.
- The problematic line of code is `before { @user.safe }`.
- The problem is a `NoMethodError` which means you're trying to call a method on an object for which that method is not defined.
- It tells you specifically that there is no method `safe` for `#<User:0x503b848>` which is an instance of the `User` class.  From the context you should be able to deduce that it's referring to the `@user` variable in this context.

This is **way more** than enough information to deduce what **cause** of the problem is: you're calling `@user.safe` on line 86, and there is no such method `safe` for `@user`.

The **solution** to the problem is you probably mean to call `save`, not `safe`.

You have a few other failures for a couple other reasons.  See if you can read the information in the error messages to understand the causes of the problems, then it should be easy to figure out on your own how to fix those problems.

Comment: Thank you Amit, it taught me that I have to read the error messages in more datail. That was not clear to me. Many thanks again for explaining in so much detail